RPi5: error while loading shared libraries: libcef.so: ELF load command address/offset not page-aligned
NOTE: I think this is the right community to ask this question, although I'm not sure since it touches on topics like programming (https://stackoverflow.com/), linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and raspberry (here).
This is my problem:
With flutter I'm developing a desktop application for a linux environment, specifically to run on raspberry pi. I need that given a URL my application has a widget to render websites. For this I have added the packages 'flutter_linux_webview' and 'webview_flutter'. This is a snippet of my pubspec.yaml file:
name: station_screen
publish_to: none
version: 1.5.0-beta+2
environment:
    sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    flutter_linux_webview: 0.1.2
    webview_flutter: 3.0.4

When I build, the binary, which is called 'station_screen', is built correctly. In the same folder as the binary, a 'lib/' folder has been created and inside it a 'libcef.so' file of 1.3Gb is created.
On a raspberry pi4, I can run the binary from a terminal, I enter the binary folder and type: "./station_screen" and so far there are no errors, everything works fine. However, when running it on a raspberry pi5 I get the following error:
./station_screen: error while loading shared libraries: libcef.so: ELF load command address/offset not page-aligned
As I've investigated there are significant differences between pi4 and pi5, that's why I did the build from pi5 and when I run the binary I get the same error.
For further testing, I'm doing the build without using the 'flutter_linux_webview' and 'webview_flutter' packages and it runs fine on pi4 and p5.
For more details:
This is the output when typing in a terminal lsb_release -a on raspberries pi4 and pi5 respectively:
Pi 4
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye

Pi 5
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

This is the output when typing in a terminal uname -a on raspberries pi4 and pi5 respectively:
Pi4
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Pi5
Linux raspberrypi 6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 (2024-10-08) aarch64 GNU/Linux


Are you running a 32-bit userland (this is not the same as the kernel, which is 64-bit)?  If so have a look here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=358453 The suggestion is to use the same kernel as is used on the Pi 4, which does not have the tweaks that may be part of the problem.  If that works, you should try using the 64-bit version of the OS if possible.

it isn't true, i'm using a 64bit userland.

Well, as popcornmix's answer said I opened a terminal and typed:
sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt

and Added this at the end of the file:
kernel=kernel8.img

If you just write one line you can type:
sudo bash -c "echo 'kernel=kernel8.img' >> /boot/firmware/config.txt"

then reboot the pi.
NOTE: in others version of raspberry pi the config.txt file may be in /boot/config.txt instead.
